# How do I use Ruby on Rails to log into a 3rd-party authentication server with a CSRF token?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, csrf

How do I use Ruby on Rails to log into a 3rd-party authentication server with a CSRF token?

I've searched for solutions on token validation in Rails, but as far as I can discern, they only help me log into my own app's authentication system (devise, etc.), and not a 3rd party's domain.

From the 3rd party, I've been provided a URL to POST to, a URL to obtain a CSRF token, and a URL to use to logout with the token.

Thank you!

Comment: You can probably just use raw HTTP requests?

Comment: So I assign a variable to the URL's response, and then use that as the csrf field in my login form?